# wicket and jquery-ui menu; menu renders as an unordered list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, wicket

I have been looking at using wicket in conjunction with jquery-ui. Here is what i have:

```
<wicket:head>

 <script src="/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-    1.10.3.custom.css">

<script>
$("#menu").menubar();
</script>

</wicket:head>

<wicket:panel>


    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Character</a>
        <ul>
        <li>sdf</li>
        <li>sfs</li>
        <li>we</li>
        </ul>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Corporation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Alliance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fleet</a></li>
    </ul>
```

When I add this panel to my page it appears as a unordered list with no jquery magic.

Anyone know if there is something within wicket I need to do to make this work?

I have verified that both the jquery script and the css is being picked up

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to put the JS code in $(document).ready(function() { ... });

Answer (score 0):

> When I add this panel to my page it appears as a unordered list with
>   no jquery magic.

Christophs comment is correct. The script needs to be executed on document load.

The "Wicket Way" of adding JQuery functionality to a component is by creating a Behavior that takes care of loading the javascript and css files and adding the javascript on document load. Something like this:

```
public class JQueryMenuBehavior extends Behavior{

    @Override
    public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response){
        response.renderJavascriptReference("/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js");
        response.renderCSSReference("/jquery/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css");
        response.renderOnDomReadyJavascript("$('#menu').menubar();");
    }
}
```

Then simply add this behavior to a "normal" Wicket unordered list and you have your JQuery menu. You should probably make the id "#menu" configurable.

This way you have a reusable behavior that you can add to any list you want to be displayed as a jquery menu.

Comment: In wicket 1.5 AbstractBehaviour is deprecated and is replaced with Behaviour. Upon changing this it throws an error regarding the override annotation:

The method renderHead(IHeaderResponse) of type JQueryMenuBehavior must override a superclass method

Comment: Sorry, the code was for Wicket 1.4. I updated the code above for Wicket 6.x.